# Incrementing over a list in a list (encapsulated list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm having some troubles getting my for loop working, which is supposed to create a number of labels in a window.
Here is the code snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#Frame 1: components
frame1 = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=0)
items = ['REED', 'PIR', 'VIBR', 'REED', 'PIR']
for r in items:
    tk.Label(frame1, text=items[r]).grid(row=r,column=0)
#Frame 2: statusList
frame2 = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=1)
status = [[True, False, True, False],
         ['14:00:00', '13:24:31', '15:58:32', '08:33:01']]
for r in status:
    for s in status[r]:
        tk.Label(frame2, text=status[r][s]).grid(row=s,column=r)
root.mainloop()
```

It outputs the Error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Which indicated me that my usage of the for-loop is wrong. I've looked up some information and found that I can certainly loop over a list and have it go through each item and for example print that item, but as of yet I don't know how to implement that idea when there's an encapsulated list that I want to loop through.

Comment: Don't change the question to include the answer, it's unhelpful for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
for r in items:
    tk.Label(frame1, text=items[r]).grid(row=r,column=0)
```

That's not how python's for loop works. In the for loop's body, `r` is not the index of the item in `items`, it *is* the item, so you'd need :

```
for item in items:
    tk.Label(frame1, text=item).grid(row=???,column=0)
```

but it seems you also want the index of the item to pass as the `row` argument for `.grid()`. For this you can use `enumerate(seq)` which yields a `(index, item)` tuple for each element of `seq`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    tk.Label(frame1, text=item).grid(row=index,column=0)
```

Note that you also have a similar issue here:

```
status = [[True, False, True, False],
         ['14:00:00', '13:24:31', '15:58:32', '08:33:01']]
for r in status:
    for s in status[r]:
        tk.Label(frame2, text=status[r][s]).grid(row=s,column=r)
```

Comment: Ok, this really fixed my loop problem, only for me to find out that I have window problems as well. But that's a story for another day I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `for s in status[r]:` with `for s in r:`

`r` contains an element of `status` (in this case the `list` to iterate over in the inner `for` loop), *not an index*.

You should also replace `text=status[r][s]` with `text = s`, for the same reason.

If you want just the indices, you can use:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
```

for some `list` `lst` and if you want both indices and elements (in this case, you need the indices to pass in the column and row values), use:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
```

Comment: :O gasps
Not what I expected, thanks for the speedy answer. I'll try it out

Comment: If you do want to iterate over indices, you can use `for i in range(len(lst)):`, but in most cases you want to iterate over the actual elements.

Comment: @yinnonsanders better use `enumerate(lst)` if you want both the items and their indices.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers true, missed that in the code. You covered it much better in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You also have an issue around the labels of `frame1`. You can fix it if you rely on [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for row, text in enumerate(items):
    tk.Label(frame1, text=text).grid(row=row,column=0)
```